# Rapid form submission

Tags: javascript, dom-events

An on-line reservation system (reserveamerica.com) has a policy that permits forms requesting a reservation be submitted only at 8:00 a.m. Eastern. The competition for some venues is intense so there are a number of people all submitting forms at one time.

To avoid rapidly pressing the "Book Reservation" hundreds of times, I would like code to do that instead. One, to make it more efficient, and two: to improve chances of getting a reservation.

My question is, is this possible and if so, how should I proceed?

Answer (score -1):

In your program, on your server side language, you can write a program logic, which checks the request from a particular IP, and matches the duration between the current and last request.

If the duration is too short, you can code accordingly to ignore such requests or reply with a message that you can make a request only once in 5 seconds.